# Watir fails to find element intermittently

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I have the following code using Watir to check some boxes on a javascript form.

```
NBA_NORTH_AMERICA = 'https://sports.bwin.com/en/sports#leagueIds=6004&sportId=7'
MONEY_LINE = 'cat_43'
TOTALS = 'cat_48'

def method

    browser = Watir::Browser.new 
    browser.goto NBA_NORTH_AMERICA
    browser.checkbox(:id => TOTALS).parent.span.click unless browser.checkbox(:id => TOTALS).checked?
    browser.checkbox(:id => MONEY_LINE).parent.span.click unless browser.checkbox(:id => MONEY_LINE).checked? == false

    browser.divs(:class => 'layout4').each do |event|

    end
    browser.close
end
```

It works about half the time but the other half it throws this error:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:536:in `assert_element_found': unable to locate element, using {:tag_name=>"span"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
```

on the line for the second checkbox (Money Line). From inspecting in firefox I can see that the checkbox and span elements both exist. What's happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually these are race conditions caused by the asynchronous nature of javascript. Add a wait like this:

```
browser.checkbox(:id => TOTALS).when_present.checked?
```

Comment: I've tried doing this but the when_present times out (30 seconds) despite the fact I can see the element is clearly there.

Comment: Where is it failing the checkbox or inside your loop? If it is inside the loop, does the action in the loop change what is on the page?

Comment: On the checkbox (well the span that I click to check the checkbox)

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the parent. Try: `browser.checkbox(:id => TOTALS).when_present.parent.span.click`

Comment: hmm seems to be the same

Comment: Ah, ok, I just ran this and see what is going on. When you click one of the checkboxes it kicks off some javascript that changes the DOM. It is still changing things when Watir goes to click the element. You need to wait for the javascript to finish. If you notice this button goes away and then comes back after the first click. So adding this it seems to work: `browser2.button(:id => 'favorites-tip').wait_until_present`

Comment: Even with that I still sometimes get the same error. I can't really see a pattern to reproduce it reliably though.

Comment: The problem is the javascript, if you have a long enough wait, it will work. Figuring out what to wait for is the difficult part. That last suggestion solved it for me with a handful of runs.